# changing cakephp folder bake not run

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-bake

I copied my cakephp project in new folder and after that I changed folder`s name. but when I run cake bake form 'myNewProjectFolder/bin/' it use database connection info from old folder!!

another problem is it make nothing! not at all! and it do not show any error.
my sample:

> D:\wamp64\www\otomasion\bin>cake bake all tbl_users
>
> Welcome to CakePHP v3.4.12 Console
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- App : src Path: D:\wamp64\www\otomasion\src\ PHP : 5.6.25
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- Bake All
>   --------------------------------------------------------------- One moment while associations are detected.
>
> D:\wamp64\www\otomasion\bin>

"otomasion" is my new folder name.

Comment: did you also copy your database credentials to the new folder?

Comment: no. I created new one